# 403 error when accessing azure defender 365 using azure ad application

Tags: azure-active-directory, windows-defender

I am trying to access microsoft defender end point using application. I am following the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/exposed-apis-create-app-webapp?view=o365-worldwide)

my jwt token response is as follow

```
    {
  "aud": "https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/aa551af3-e811-4451-b20c-c5b84fb2845b/",
  "iat": 1677834504,
  "nbf": 1677834504,
  "exp": 1677838404,
  "aio": "E2ZgYGg1iK74E3KLOZTt6LdK24aHAA==",
  "app_displayname": "test",
  "appid": "3c98fbaf-4528-4469-9228-1da89796674b",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/aa551af3-e811-4451-b20c-c5b84fb2845b/",
  "oid": "7e34779b-d23b-43c0-9fd1-6e1433ac7390",
  "rh": "0.AXEA8xpVqhHoUUSyDMW4T7KEW2UEePwXINRAoMUwcCJHG5JxAAA.",
  "roles": [
    "Machine.Isolate",
    "SecurityConfiguration.ReadWrite.All",
    "IntegrationConfiguration.ReadWrite",
    "Url.Read.All",
    "Ip.Read.All",
    "Ti.ReadWrite",
    "Ti.Read.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Ti.ReadWrite.All",
    "SecurityRecommendation.Read.All",
    "Alert.Read.All",
    "Software.Read.All",
    "SecurityConfiguration.Read.All",
    "File.Read.All",
    "Machine.CollectForensics",
    "SecurityBaselinesAssessment.Read.All",
    "Vulnerability.Read.All",
    "Library.Manage",
    "Machine.Read.All",
    "Score.Read.All",
    "RemediationTasks.Read.All",
    "AdvancedQuery.Read.All"
  ],
  "sub": "7e34779b-d23b-43c0-9fd1-6e1433ac7390",
  "tenant_region_scope": "AS",
  "tid": "aa551af3-e811-4451-b20c-c5b84fb2845b",
  "uti": "AaYxgeKwO0KqfhJrlhFqAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

when I tried to access end point I am getting below 403 error

[image]

I am using azure personal account. can anyone help me in this regard
my end point is [here](https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/alerts)

Thanks

Comment: What endpoint you are running with that access token?

Comment: @Sridevi https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/alerts

Comment: Could you confirm whether you have an active Microsoft Defender license or not?

Comment: @Sridevi Yes I have

Comment: Could you check whether you can see alerts via Defender Portal or not with this link: https://security.microsoft.com/alerts

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added `API permissions` as below:

[image]

Now I generated one **access token** via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I decoded the above access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) and got **`roles`** claim with **same permissions** as you like below:

[image]

When I used the above access token to call below endpoint, I got **same error** as you like below:

```
GET https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/alerts
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can make use of below **MS Graph API query** to get list of alerts:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts_v2
```

To run that query, you need to add **`SecurityAlert.Read.All`** in your application like this:

[image]

Make sure to grant **admin consent** to the added permission as below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** by changing scope to *Microsoft Graph* like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

I decoded the above access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) and got **`roles`** claim with added permission like below:

[image]

When I ran below query by including above access token, I got the **response** successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts_v2
```

**Response:**

[image]

I got **blank** in my response as I don't have any alerts. To **confirm** that, you can check alerts in **[Microsoft 365 Defender](https://security.microsoft.com/)** portal like this:

[image]

**Reference:**
[List alerts_v2 - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-list-alerts_v2?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: I cannot even select the API permission "WindowsDefenderATP" as shown in your very first step. There is no API section like that - even not when typing into "APIs your organization uses" (E5 license). Seems like tools using these "old" endpoints still work with all those new "Security..." permission set of the Graph API - besides Machine.Read.All - I can't get this to work. Overall this is poorly documented and these constant renamings and reorganizations are very frustrating